# Convert string 2 decimal places in Java

Tags: java

In Java, I am trying to parse a string of format "0.##" to a float. The string should always have 2 decimal places.

```
public ArrayList getFixRateDetails (String merchantccy,String paymodetype,String amount) 

{
        String returnAmt ="";

ArrayList list= new ArrayList();

        float value=-1;
        try {
            NiCurrencyConverterProcessor nicc= new NiCurrencyConverterProcessor();
            list=nicc.getFixRateDetails(merchantccy,paymodetype);
            Float i = (Float.parseFloat((String) list.get(0)));
            Float j =  (Float.parseFloat(amount));


            value=i*j;
            list.set(0, value);
            list.add(2, i);
            GenericExceptionLog.log("PayPalUtility.java : In getFixRateDetails() : value:"+list,"paymenttarasectionsevlet111");
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            String ReturnAmt = df.format(returnAmt);
            returnAmt=String.valueOf(value).trim();
            GenericExceptionLog.log("PayPalUtility.java : In getFixRateDetails() : value:"+returnAmt,"paymenttarasectionsevlet222");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            GenericAsyncLogger.Logger(t,"ERROR","DB","Transaction","MIGSTxnUtility.java","postingAmtConversion()","NA","NA","","","paymenttarasectionsevlet");
            //GenericExceptionLog.exceptionJava(t,"postingAmtConversion()", "MIGSTxnUtility");
        }
            return list;
        }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Use `String.format()`

Comment: I am try this code but it will not converted

Comment: Please do your self a favour and use BigDecimal instead of float especially for money calculations. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the formatted output to the different variable (ReturnAmt) and in the log you are printing returnAmt. It is obvious that it will print the value without formatting.

Try

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
returnAmt = formatter.format(value);
```

For more information refer [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Example:

```
public static void main(String...args){
        String returnAmt ="";
        Float i = 100f;
        Float j =  200f;
        Float value=i*j;
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        returnAmt = formatter.format(value);
        System.out.println(returnAmt);
    }
```

OUTPUT:

> 20000.00